Question on unwinding cross-currency swap
Hoping someone can help me understand 'Notional Exchange Unwind Value - NEUV' when terminating a cross currency swap prematurely. Where the NEUV is essentially the profit/loss of the notional exchange amount using the latest spot fx rate.
As I understand it when unwinding the swap early, the net fee is essentially = FV of the two legs of swap + Notional Exchange Unwind Value
Had the xccy swap be allowed to mature naturally, the notional principal swapped at the end is the same as inception, where the notional amt is unaffected by changes in spot FX rate. So why is it then that when you're unwinding the swap early, you are made to pay/receive the NEUV? shouldn't the fee be just the FV?

I don't really care for these terms with acronyms that differ from system to system.
Fundamentally, any existing cross-currency swap has two legs. Suppose a EURUSD XCS and the EURUSD exchange rate is 1.07. Suppose you are paying the interest on the EUR leg (and therefore paying a EUR notional at maturity) and you receiving the USD interest (and receiving a USD notional at maturity).
This XCS may have net present values of each leg as follows:
Eur Leg: -105.0mm EUR 
Usd Leg: +112.5mm USD 
Net NPV in USD = 0.15mm USD 
Net NPV in EUR = 0.14mm EUR 
You can if you want, just terminate the XCS at the prevailing NPV, i.e. terminate all future cashflows for an exchange of 0.15m USD or 0.14m EUR.
But if you do that you will suddenly gain a large spot FX exposure, approximately 105m EUR worth.
This is why XCS are not generally terminated with a single net present value offsetting fee.
The way to do it which does not result in either party experiencing a large change in FX exposure is to terminate each leg for a cashflow in that currency.
I.e. Pay 105mm EUR and Rec 112.5mm USD. Doing the exchange in this way only results in the counterparties changing their XCS basis risks (and fixed rate risks if either leg has fixed rate instead of floating).

Thanks for this
Going by your example, suppose a cross ccy swap is initiated at FX rate of 1.07. 105mm EUR and 112.5 mm USD is swapped on initiation and maturity.
My understanding is that at any period subsequent to initiation, the NPV of the swap is = PV leg 1 - (latest spot FX * PV leg 2). So if you terminate the swap early, you're realising FX gain/losses from difference between 1.07 and whatever latest FX rate is.
Lets say if you're planning to unwind the swap 1 day before maturity and the FX rate has since initiation moved against you, wouldnt you just wait 1 more day?

The amount USD and EUR exchanged at maturity is a fixed amount and is known 1d before maturity. It has a value measured at the prevailing FX rate. That value does not materially change from one day to the next. Also don't forget that XCSs begin with a notional exchange the other way round, so any FX losses on the derivative are cash gains on the currencies that you hold in cash from the initial exchange.
